# R: problems with reading excel file and using ca library

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to read file and build correspondence analysis, but I can't do this, because reading excel is wrong. 
My file looks like

```
            a   b   c   d   e
1mbank.ru   0   0   0   0   0
akbars.ru   0   0   0   0   0
alfabank.ru 1   0   0   1   0
avangard.ru 0   0   0   0   0
bank-hlynov.ru  0   0   0   0   0
```

When I use

```
df <- read.table("tasks_correspondence_t.xlsx", sep=";")
```

or

```
channel <- odbcConnectExcel("tasks_correspondence_t.xlsx")
df <- sqlFetch(channel, “tasks_correspondence_t”)
```

I get

```
F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6
1mbank.ru  0  0  0  0  0
akbars.ru  0  0  0  0  0 
alfabank.ru  1  0  0  1  0 
avangard.ru  0  0  0  0  0
bank-hlynov.ru  0  0  0  0  0
```

And when I try to use `ca` and `res.ca <- CA(df, graph = F)`
I get

```
The following variables are not quantitative:  F1
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @AleksandrVoitov I need to get graph like this `https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLqEA.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample usage would be:

```
library(ca)
df <- read.table("tasks_correspondence_t.txt", header = TRUE)
row.names(df) = df$id
df = df[,-1]
fit <- ca(df)
plot(fit)
```

Data in **tasks_correspondence_t.txt**:

```
id  a   b   c   d   e
1mbank.ru   2   2   2   2   2
akbars.ru 2 2   2   2   2
alfabank.ru 1   2   1   2   2
avangard.ru 2   2   1   2   1
bank-hlynov.ru  2   2   2   1   2
```